# Which azkar are mustahab and which are farz

Tags: fard, dhikr

Which adhkar are mustahab and which are fard.  I would like to know that which adhkar are fard and which are mustahab. Please if you could elaborate the answer.

Comment: There are no fard ones.

Comment: Dhikr is a very big topic and has several "categories" it is therefore better to specify. Especially as you ask for an elaborated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most adhkar are mustahab. Fard ones are those said in Salah, Adhaan, Talbiyah, Takbirat al-Tashriq, replying to Salam, saying Tasmiyah on slaughtering cattle etc.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/253005/the-virtue-of-remembering-allah-dhikr-may-he-be-exalted-is-everyone-who-remembers-allah-little-a-hypocrite

> Remembering Allah, may He be exalted, may be obligatory, as in the
>   case of takbeerat al-ihram (the takbeer said when starting the
>   prayer), or it may be mustahabb.
>
> Dhikr may be obligatory; obligatory adhkaar include some of the
>   adhkaar of the prayer, such as takbeerat al-ihraam and recitation of
>   Qur’an. Obligatory adhkaar also include the adhaan and iqaamah,
>   according to the view that they are a communal obligation (fard
>   kifaayah). Returning greetings of salaam, and saying Bismillah when
>   slaughtering an animal for meat are also obligatory adhkaar.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for that? (See [answer]).

Comment: Evidence for what? That Salah is Fard?

Comment: But none of the dhikr within salat is fard. You always have several options as they are sunnah.

Comment: Qirat, Takbir etc. are Dhikr.

Comment: And all of them are sunnah, with a few exceptions. But OP didn't clarify whether he means dhikr in general which in first place is du'a or dhikr we say on daily occasions and situations or dhikr related to a worship. And the schools of fiqh rarley have a consensus whether a dhikr within a worship is fard or not.